# Using script + screen through child_process

Tags: node.js, bash, pipe, child-process

**Solved**:
I had to add `\r\n` at `program.stdin.write(data)` (something like this `program.stdin.write(data+'\r\n')`) and it worked.

It seems that if i don't put `\r\n`, it doesn't triggers, its like typing in a line without pressing enter so it will never be processed.

===========================================================================

I need to access screen through child_process, but it doesn't works properly.
First I tried to access using spawn.

```
const {spawn} = require('child_process');
const program = spawn('screen',['-x User/Aplication']);

program.stdout.on('data',data=>{
//Something
})

function writeTo(data){
program.stdin.write(data);
}
```

But i got the error "Must be connected to a terminal error". After some research i found a solution, use `script`+`spawn` to make a pseudo-console.

```
const {spawn} = require('child_process');
const program = spawn('script',['/dev/null']);//Pseudo-console
program.stdin.write('screen -x User/Aplication');//I access to screen through the pseudo-console, and it works.

program.stdout.on('data',data=>{
//Something
})

function writeTo(data){
program.stdin.write(data);
}
```

But... when I try to use `writeTo`, it doesn't works.

```
writeTo('Some command here')//Does nothing.
```

And somehow, when I pipe my console input, it works!

```
process.stdin.pipe(program.stdin);
```

Then I type something in my console and it proxies properly to connected `screen`.

**Issue**: It doesn't proxies properly when using `program.stdin.write`, but somehow, it works when i pipe my console `process.stdin.pipe(program.stdin)`

**Observation 1**: I made a short echo-program and it worked with both `program.stdin.write` and `process.stdin.pipe(program.stdin)`

**echo.js**

```
process.stdin.on('data',data=>{
console.log(`[Input]${data}`);
})
```

**main.js**

```
const {spawn} = require('child_process');
const program = spawn('node',['echo.js']);

program.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);

function writeTo(data){
program.stdin.write(data);
}

writeTo('Test');//Output: [Input]Test
process.stdin.pipe(program.stdin);//I type 'something'. Output: [Input]something
```

**Observation 2**: When using `script`+`screen` and piping my console, `program.stdin.write` only 'buffers' and `process.stdin.pipe` loads that buffer and sends it with what i typed.

```
program.stdin.write('He');//screen receives nothing
program.stdin.write('llo');//screen receives nothing
process.stdin.pipe(program.stdin);//I type ' world!'. screen receives 'Hello world!'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add `\r\n` at `program.stdin.write(data)` (something like this `program.stdin.write(data+'\r\n')`) and it worked.

It seems that if i don't put `\r\n`, it doesn't triggers as a new line and it doesn't sends it, its like typing `all commands in a line without pressing enter so it will never be processed`.

Answer (score 0):

it may not be the whole problem, but the second argument to `spawn` should have each argument in a separate array element.

```
const program = spawn('screen',['-x', 'User/Aplication']);
```

Comment: I solved it, i had to add "\r\n" at `program.stdin.write(data)`, without it was like typing all in only one line without pressing enter and my program doesn't works like that. Thats the reason why it was "buffering" and sending only when piping since my console added "\r\n" at the end.